# MySQL Character Encodings

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a large database that was originally created with latin1 encoding and latin1_swedish_ci collations.

I've made a lot of changes and now I am using Doctrine2, which uses `SET NAMES UTF8` before queries.  I was using the Yii framework previously which was also setup to use UTF-8.  Basically I overlooked all of this at the start but from what I understand, I've been writing UTF-8 data to the database, although it's all supposed to be latin1.

I'd like to convert my database to utf-8 but have no idea how to do it safely and ensure I'm not losing data.

**Two questions:**

1. Is there a way to ensure that I have done this correctly? I have like 2 GB of data so I can't just scan through it to test, but are there certain characters that I can look for to determine if the database is using UTF-8 already?
2. What is the proper way to convert everything?  I've seen some people say I have to mysqldump and re-import (with certain flags, http://blog.makezine.com/2007/05/08/mysql-database-migration-latin/ and http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8). Others say you can `ALTER TABLE...` per column (http://www.bothernomore.com/2008/12/16/character-encoding-hell/). And I've seen some command like `SET utf8` as part of an `ALTER TABLE` I think, but I don't know if that works.

**EDIT:**

I've dumped the data and have found several accented characters.  Would this indicate that the data itself is UTF-8? If so, I htink the instructions here apply since I can just "convert" to blob and back safely http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

**EDIT AGAIN:**

After doing what I read in the previous link, I found that comparing the data, I was missing all characters after the first non-ascii(?) one.  So I had titles set with curly single quotes and the new database had that character and all characters after it missing. As an example, here is the code I was running:

```
ALTER TABLE articles CHANGE title title VARBINARY(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE articles CHANGE title title VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL;
```

Somehow that caused me to lose data.

But if I dump, change the charset for each table from latin1 to utf8, it works.  I'd prefer to just modify things rather than dump and re-create but I'll resort to it if no one has any other suggestions or ideas based on this.

Comment: I had similar problem. I use bulk maintenance feature of HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the dump and reimport.  I followed this guide mostly: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL

If anyone else is in my situation (you have UTF-8 data stored in a latin1 database which you've always accessed by calling `SET NAMES utf8`, then here's what you can try (my modifications from the above source).

```
mysqldump -h example.org --user=foo -p -c --insert-ignore --skip-set-charset -r dump.sql dbname
```

Double check that it is UTF-8 (mine was)

```
file dump.sql
```

Do the conversion on the dump

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/CHARSET=latin1/CHARSET=utf8/g;' dump.sql
```

Create a new database (I didn't drop the old just in case)

```
mysql --user=foo -p --execute="CREATE DATABASE dbnameutf8 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
```

Import

```
mysql --user=foo -p --default-character-set=utf8 dbnameutf8 < dump.sql
```

Hope that can help someone else.  Just remember, the `ALTER TABLE...` stuff may not work (it did not in my case).

Answer (score 2):

To check things you can do something like:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1 
JOIN table_1 t2 on t1.guid = t2.guid AND
t1.field_1 <> t2.field_1 COLLATE UTF-8
```

Basically, on the fly, change the collation of the column and see if there's going to be anything that is going to go wrong.

You definitely don't need to re-import everything, `ALTER TABLE` to the new encoding should be fine, assuming everything will convert OK.

Comment: Do I have to `alter table` and individually change all string columns? That seems to be what I'm reading

Comment: Also, tried: `mysql> SELECT t1.* FROM articles t1 JOIN articles t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.title <> t2.title COLLA
TE utf8_general_ci LIMIT 10;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

Comment: If you are doing your ENTIRE db.. possibly just use sqldump instead, or programmatically loop every single column. Have you tried using a nested `COLLATE`? like `t1.title <> (t2.title COLLATE utf8_general_ci) COLLATE latin1`

Comment: Still an error. `mysql> SELECT t1.* FROM articles t1 JOIN articles t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.title <> (t2.title COLL
ATE utf8_general_ci) collate latin1 LIMIT 10;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'` I'm thinking of looping over every column to do the "conversion" to blob and back in UTF-8.  I'm on Amazon RDS and don'w want to spend even more money on I/O operations to dump and import.